# Where is the js script written for selection of attributes in magento 2

Tags: magento2, script

I am unable to find one ajax script .
Can any body tell me where is the script written for this page https://prnt.sc/szvwqu
On selection of attributes , how the price gets changed ? where can i find the script for this?

Answer (score 0):

For the price, there is a json in your page with all variants and prices. So no ajax request is needed to change the product price. If you take a look on your page source you will find something like this:
[image]

You have to search "spConfig".

This json is created here: **\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig**

The JS that renders this options on frontend is located in: **/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

The JS that updates the price value is located here: **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js**

Comment: Thanx. i want to ask one thing . when i am doing some customisation for the price displayed here https://prnt.sc/t00ymw it is getting affected in related products too https://prnt.sc/t00ytn. How can i separate these two . i want to customise only above price

Comment: i dont know what page is that, but for sure there is a product list with a simple variant pre loaded. In my case, i had to load a simple variant based on some rule (color, special price etc) So i overrided this template, /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml and passed a simple variant to the getProductPrice method on line 74.